# Is it easy to use Sun Burn engine for WP7 game development?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sunburn

I was wondering if anyone has tried to develop a game using the SunBurn game engine for the **Windows Phone 7** platform.

How good is documentation, examples, etc?
Is it easy in use and implementation?

Any feedback would be greatly welcome.

Comment: This is not a discussion site; whether something is "easy" is extremely subjective.

Comment: @Joe my mistake. Feel free to readd your close vote. I've removed my vote because although you can't objectively say whether something is easy, you can objectively comment about the coverage of their documentation and examples.

Comment: @Noctrine: Apparently, I cannot re-vote. Since there aren't four others that can agree with me though, it's still pretty academic. Still, there's not really an answerable question here, other than a link to the Sun Burn documentation. I don't think the SO format is very good for "product reviews".

Answer (score 2):

The SunBurn Game Engine has a free version called the SunBurn Framework:

http://www.synapsegaming.com/products/sunburn/framework/

It doesn't include the editor or deferred rendering, but it uses the same api and design as the game engine.

Also SunBurn uses the exact same code and assets for Windows, Xbox, and Windows Phone 7, so it's just as easy to develop on all three platforms.

-JohnK (SunBurn team member)